# how to get whole html content and store in a variable for reusability in my Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**In Alert my html content showing but on Click it is not working . My Requirement is User When Click On first button Then My First table want to load on table-content div,If user click on second button then my second table want to load on table content div helpme how to get whole html content in a div **

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#first').hide();
  $('#second').hide();
  var f = $('#first').html();
  var r = $('#second').html();
  alert(f);
  alert(r);
  $('#fst').click(function(){
  $('.table-content').html()= f;
  });
  $('#snd').click(function(){
  $('.table-content').html()= r;
  });
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.f1{
width:100%;

}
table,th,td{
  border:1px solid #ff9900;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.f1 td{
text-align:center;
}
.f2{
width:100%;

}
.f2 td{
text-align:center;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:5px;
}
.table-content{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #ff8800;
  }
.btns{
text-align:center;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
<table class="f1">
  <tr height="50">
    <th width="33%">column11</th>
    <th width="34%">column12</th>
    <th width="33%">column13</th>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
<div id="second">
<table class="f2">
  <tr height="50">
    <th width="33%">column21</th>
    <th width="34%">column22</th>
    <th width="33%">column23</th>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-content"></div>
  <div class="btns">
  <button id="fst">Frist</button>
  <button id="snd">Second</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use setter method like `$('.table-content').html(f);`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#first').hide();
  $('#second').hide();
  var f = $('#first').html();
  var r = $('#second').html();

  $('#fst').click(function() {
    $('.table-content').html(f);
  });
  $('#snd').click(function() {
    $('.table-content').html(r);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.f1 {
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ff9900;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.f1 td {
  text-align: center;
}
.f2 {
  width: 100%;
}
.f2 td {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;

}
.table-content {
  width: 99%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8800;
}
.btns {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <table class="f1">
    <tr height="50">
      <th width="33%">column11</th>
      <th width="34%">column12</th>
      <th width="33%">column13</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <table class="f2">
    <tr height="50">
      <th width="33%">column21</th>
      <th width="34%">column22</th>
      <th width="33%">column23</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-content"></div>
  <div class="btns">
    <button id="fst">Frist</button>
    <button id="snd">Second</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: oh!! Thanks Its Nice

Comment: why the horizental scrollbar will come how to fixed it

Comment: horizontal scroll comes because you have `width:100%` for `.table-content` and also have border of 1px. Just updated the code to avoid scroll.

Answer (score 1):

`html()` also takes a parameter as content.

Try putting your variables inside like this `$('.table-content').html(f);`

Comment: Ok Thank you I Try To Do That .

Comment: Nice Answer Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can make some minor changes in your js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#first,#second').hide();
  var html="";
  $('#fst').click(function(){
   html=$.trim($(this).html());
  });
  $('#snd').click(function(){
   html=$.trim($(this).html());
  });
  $('.table-content').html(html);
});
```